# Your Device is not compatible with this version error in "Moto e" Devices on play store

Tags: android

Your Device is not compatible with this version error in "Moto e" Devices on play store 
Its Permission in all library AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.firebug.cocoapay.android" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:name=".main.CocoaPayApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash_Activity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: Check your [merged manifest](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html), as other permissions may be coming from libraries, in addition to changes to your `minSdkVersion` and such.

Comment: Only four permission are there .   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />  as i tell above

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

Comment: You are welcome to post your entire merged manifest, and perhaps we will see something that explains the problem.